# why are jpeg previews included with each photo in the directory?

Tags: nautilus, 15.10, photo-management, jpeg, digikam

i have uploaded a bunch of RAW photos on my ubuntu device from an SD card, and what i am finding is that in each directory where my photos are stored, there is also a jpeg preview right next to it. meaning, if i have a folder with 20 photos i have taken in it, there will be 40 files. 
i dont know if this is just how photo management is done on linux, jpeg previews arent something i have ever had to sort through before

id like to know if there is a way to turn not have those jpeg previews there? is there some command to configure such that the jpeg previews would maybe go to a different directory?

im have to sort through them picture by picture in luminance instead of just being able to highlight all the photos i want to use, kind of a pain in the butt.

this is happening in nautilus as well as in digikam, but it does not happen in shotwell...

here is a  [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ljqE6.png) of what im talking about

Answer (score 0):

Not clear which version of ubuntu are you using. I have tried this on 12.04.

Assuming that you are seeing image previews on nautilus, the file manager, click edit/preferences, last tab Preview. Set up the show thumbnails option to never or to other settings to your liking.

Comment: no, i added a link to a screen shot of what im talking about.  whenever i upload a RAW image to the computer, a JPEG preview of that photo is also uploaded. so its a second file in the same directory, right next to the RAW photo i uploaded.

Comment: ive just never seen a second file for a JPEG preview of one of my photos before, and i dont want to have to see em if i can help it